# pandas getting lastrow index of excel file and appending data to it, needs some fix

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

i am trying to get last row of column `plate` and append data to it. But it gives corrupt file error even though scrapy is working properly.

I guess error is due to lines below. Where I firstly, use pandas `ExcelWriter` object, then for getting last row I use dataframe.

```
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output_res.xlsx', mode='r+',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        df_last=pd.DataFrame('output_res.xlsx')
        lastRow=df_last['plate'].iget(-1)
        df_output = pd.DataFrame(itemList)
        df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result', index=False, header=True,startrow=lastRow)
```

and variable `lastRow` is unassigned, as I guess. That's why it does not give a value to `to_excel` method

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd

class plateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapePlate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        columnA_values=df['PLATE']
        for row in columnA_values:
            global  plate_num_xlsx
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        itemList=[]
        for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
            plate = row.css('a::text').get()
            price = row.css('p::text').get()
            if plate_num_xlsx==plate.replace(" ","").strip():
                item= {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}
                itemList.append(item)
                yield  item
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": "-"}
                itemList.append(item)
                yield item

        with pd.ExcelWriter('output_res.xlsx', mode='r+',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            df_last=pd.DataFrame('output_res.xlsx')
            lastRow=df_last['plate'].iget(-1)
            df_output = pd.DataFrame(itemList)
            df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result', index=False, header=True,startrow=lastRow)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(plateScraper)
process.start()
```

gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 240, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 338, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 338, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 336, in <genexpr>
    return (self._set_referer(r, response) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 32, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, response, spider))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 79, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\SimonDarak\scrpy_00.py", line 33, in parse
    with pd.ExcelWriter('output_res.xlsx', mode='a',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._book = load_workbook(self._handles.handle, **engine_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 282, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 228, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 448, in bind_all
    self.bind_cells()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 351, in bind_cells
    for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 144, in parse
    for _, element in it:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1255, in iterator
    data = source.read(16 * 1024)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 925, in read
    data = self._read1(n)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1015, in _read1
    self._update_crc(data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 943, in _update_crc
    raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take list from parse method and put it outside class.
`itemList=[]`

```
def parse(self, response):

    for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
        plate = row.css('a::text').get()
        price = row.css('p::text').get()
        a = plate.replace(" ", "").strip()
        print(plate_num_xlsx,a,a == plate_num_xlsx)
        if plate_num_xlsx==plate.replace(" ","").strip():
            item= {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}
            itemList.append(item)
            yield  item
        else:
            item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": "-"}
            itemList.append(item)
            yield item

    with pd.ExcelWriter('output_res.xlsx', mode='r+',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        df_output = pd.DataFrame(itemList)
        df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result', index=False, header=True)
```